# Tropical Quadratic passing through 5 points.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, tropical-geometry

I am going through „Introduction to Tropical Geometry” by Diane Maclagan and Bernd Sturmfels. One exercise from the first chapter is to calculate and draw tropical quadratic passing through 5 points. Do you know how to do this other than solving hard optimization problems? The points are $(0,5),$ $(1,0),$ $(4,2),$ $(7,3),$ $(9,4).$ Ex 11 ch 1. Also, the exercise states that the curve is unique because of the position of the points.

I tried to find the curve by drawing it but it wasn’t so successful. Also computing it by hand seems so complicated.